# What is a "mean earth orbit"?

Tags: orbital-motion, terminology, definition, satellites

I have been researching about different satellite orbits online for a while now. I have read documents about low earth orbits (LEO), medium earth orbits (MEO), high elliptical orbits (HEO) and geostationary orbits (GEO). However, today I came across a new term: "Mean Earth Orbit", without google tell me exactly what it is. Does anybody know?

Answer (score 0):

The answer lies in the classic theory of fields, and the unsolvablility of the many body problem.

In short, the langrangian for a planet in orbit contains many factors and there is more than one sphere of influence effecting it.

If there are three bodies interacting with one another, there will always be two systems that overwhelm the other.

What we get is a form of angular precession based on the perturbation of two gravitational fields, one field with an initial angular momentum of orbit and the other field with a perturbative thomas precession, as a result of a flux on the angular momentum.

$ L = mvr $, $ \dot{L} = \tau $

However $ \tau $ is constrained to a potential well between the three bodies, which causes the orbit to somewhat precess in it's own ellipse.

Another explanation of a mean obit, is the average apogee and perigee of the orbit, that's the regular farthest and closest distances respectively.